# "Operation would change object type, which is not permitted." when sending email with EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, managed-ews

I'm loading an existing email from MIME data and getting this error sometimes.

For instance:

```
EmailMessage ewsMsg = new EmailMessage(service); // service is ExchangeService instance
ewsMsg.MimeContent = new MimeContent("UTF-8", mimeBytes);
ewsMsg.Send(); // ServiceRemoteException here
```

Header section of mimeBytes which cause this exception to occur:

```
From: Microsoft Outlook
    <MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36ab6ce41109e@contoso.com>
To: Arno Bost <ArnoB@contoso.com>
Subject: Undeliverable: 
Thread-Index: AQHR3esBLcRFBp+/o0msZmG72Y4S8aAeRn0L
Date: Mon, 18 Jul 2016 18:32:08 +0400
Message-ID: <fa80f868-17fe-40d1-8501-f88c836bb2d8@SLC-DC01.contoso.com>
References: <3F10E8D8921E424C8D867E5F1F5A9F1F0311848916@SLC-DC01.contoso.com>
In-Reply-To:
 <3F10E8D8921E424C8D867E5F1F5A9F1F0311848916@SLC-DC01.contoso.com>
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 05
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: SLC-DC01.contoso.com
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: All
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
Content-Type: multipart/report;
    boundary="_000_fa80f86817fe40d18501f88c836bb2d8SLCDC01contosocom_";
    report-type=delivery-status
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Other emails get sent successfully. Does it mean Exchange cannot send multipart/report emails this way?

I'm not sure this is caused by multipart/report content-type, maybe it's just a coincidence but currently I don't have other ideas as emails with other content-types (not delivery reports) do not seem to cause this exception.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this?

Comment: No, I switched to other tasks eventually.